# Blade View not rendering xml

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I am trying to create an XML file in Laravel. I am passing data to a view.

However, the XML is not rendering.

This is what I am doing in my view

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/xml'); ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

@foreach ($merchants as $merchant)
<url>
<loc>{{ $merchant->merchant_url_text }}</loc>
</url>
@endforeach

</urlset>
```

This however is just printing the variable $merchant->merchant_url_text multiple times without any structure.

Any help with what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just your browser rendering the way it is? What do you see when you view page source in the browser?

Comment: @JohnBupit When I see the page source it is showing the tags. In the same browser if I open this link http://www.promospro.com/sitemaps01_featured_page.xml, I can see properly rendered XML. Any reason why my content is not rendering properly. Also, if tags show properly in page source, does that mean it is considered an actual xml file?

Comment: If you get a 'version' error, move the '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' string to a variable and show it using `{!! $headerString !!}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not sending the headers correctly, which is why your response is being interpreted as text/html. In Laravel, you may use the header method to add a series of headers to the response before sending it back to the user. [Here's how](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses):

```
return response($content)
        ->withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml'
        ]);
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I passed data from my controller using return response()->view('sitemap', compact('merchants'))->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

Comment: @GauravMehta I have same problem so can you please send your controller and blade file code ?
I'm trying this way then showing blank page i don't know why it's happening

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Anyone render XML in Laravel Vue SPA?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, blade is a templating engine used to render html and other frontend related stuff. I don't thing you need to render xml in your blade file. Instead you can directly return xml response from your controller.

Please try this package.

https://packagist.org/packages/jailtonsc/laravel-response-xml

Edit:

If trying to build a sitemap or something similar using blade, try the following code.

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/xml'); ?>
  {{ '<?xml version="1.0"?>' }}
  {{ '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">' }}

@foreach ($merchants as $merchant)
    {{ '<url>' }}
    {{ "<loc> $merchant->merchant_url_text </loc>" }}
    {{ '</url>' }}
@endforeach

{{ '</urlset>' }}
```

Comment: I believe that the OP is trying to build an XML sitemap, for which this package is not intended.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBupit. I was going to say the same thing. The package may not be useful to generate sitemap.

Comment: @GauravMehta updated with code example for your scenario.

Comment: you may consider using `{!! !!}` instead.